# Unable to connect mongodb with ssl, getting exception com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket

Tags: java, mongodb, sockets, ssl

Trying to create a java client to connect to the Mongodb server which is secure(with authentication and self signed certificate.)

It fails with exception "com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket."

I am able to connect to the server with auth and ssl options by using robomongo client which is installed on the same machine from where I am running the code.

Also I verified java client works fine with there is only authentication in mongodb server, only with ssl it is failing.

My Code looks like this:

```
String uri = "mongodb://<user>:<password>@<ip>:<port>/admin?ssl=true&sslInvalidHostNameAllowed=true";
MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI(uri);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
DB db = mongoClient.getDB(connectionString.getDatabase());
```

Versions:

Mongo v3.4.5

Jdk 1.8

Mongo-java-driver 3.2.2

Full stack trace:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:462)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:205)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendMessage(CommandHelper.java:89)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:43)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:201)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with certificate and that you are using IP in uri. Try to use hostname or add alternative name to certificate.

Here is one more possible solution: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3NGB_5.1.0.3/ioc/ts_liberty_ip.html

Comment: Actually with the same certificate I am able to connect the server using robomongo (UI based client which is installed on my machine). The server is running inside a container and I am giving localhost for CN.